# How do you disable sounds for the virtual keyboard used by Windows Store Apps?

Tags: c#, audio, keyboard, windows-store-apps, virtual-keyboard

I've tried scouring the web but I haven't been able to find any documentation on this issue. I have a really simple problem. My Windows App Store application has a TextBox which subscribes to KeyDown events and plays its own audio for when a key is pressed. Thus, I want to disable the default sounds that you hear when you hit a key on devices that use the Windows virtual keyboard in Metro-style/Windows Store applications. How do I do this?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The sound is generated by the Keyboard and not by your application. The user however can disable the sound in the keyboards options. Also, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571065/is-it-possible-in-c-sharp-to-show-hide-and-manipulate-the-windows-8-on-screen

You can also try [this registry key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139349/c-sharp-how-to-disable-on-screen-keyboard-sound-in-windows-xp-7)

Comment: @ChrisK Interesting...so what could be a possible workaround to this?